# CodenameOne how do I check if a string contains a substring

Tags: java, arrays, string, codenameone

In "normal" Java I can use the following method to find out if a string contains a substring:

```
String string = "hello new world";
String subString = "new";

if (string.contains(subString)) {
    System.out.println("has string");
}
```

The same does not work in Codename One. Googeling around I saw a suggestion to use (what I couldn't get working):

```
string.indexOf
```

How would I perform this simple operations in Codename One?

Answer (score 2):

You can check that by calling:

```
if (new CN1String(string).contains(subString)) {
    System.out.println("has string");
}
```

Comment: Why allocate `CN1String` ? Is that in a library? `if (string.indexOf(subString) > -1)` is the equivalent of `contains()`.

Comment: thanks guys, for our help ...  I was unable to locate CN1String, though ...